# Incrementing t2 variables

Tags: c#

I have 2 variables x and y ,and they have to increment by 1, the tow variables start in 1, first x has to increment by 1,, until it reaches 25 and y stay at 1. Once it reaches 25, x has to go back to 1 and y increment to y=2, and the repeat (once x has reached 25 again y will increment by 1). here my implementation but isn't working...

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x;
            int y = 1;

            for (x = 1; x < 26; x++)
            {
                if (x == 25)
                {
                    x = 1;

                    for (y = 1; y < 30; y++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("X = " + x + ", Y = " + y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: run through it on paper. Having someone here write it for you defeats the purpose of the exercise. I will suggest that "resetting" x inside the "for x" loop is not something we normally see.

Comment: Do not manipulate index of loop. It creates more bugs than it would achieve. A loop increase slower shall be at ouside. A loop increase faster shall be inside. Your Y loops is "printing current X and Y while Y is increasing." Your expectation is opposite.

Comment: This is just bread and butter for loop stuff, see if this is close to what you want https://dotnetfiddle.net/3W8vGr

Answer (score 1):

It's not standard practice to manipulate x in a for loop. I assume you only want both variables going to 25 (edit: y now goes to 30 like in OP). So the trick is to put y on the outside and x on the inside.

In this case it's easiest to still use for loops instead of while loops.

Try something like this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < 30; y++) //y goes up 1 every time x goes up 25
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < 25; x++) //counts x to 25
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("X=" + x + " Y=" + y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the OP's question he was `y < 30`.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        for(var y = 1; y <=30 ;y++)
        {
             for(var x = 1; x<=25;x++)
             {
                  Console.WriteLine("x = {0}, y = {1}", x, y);
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WriteLine is outside of while, so it will run only one time

Comment: I kept it outside to display the final values. I corrected now

Comment: What's wrong with it? x=26 is wrong? @Enigmativity. I welcome the feedback along with downvotes...

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya where does the number 30 come from? But also, why use whiles with increments when you have `for` loops?

Comment: @seesharper 30 is being used by the OP to limit the value of y. I am just trying to follow the same logic as OP. Yes.. for loops are there but they increments are required there too... I correct my answer with use of `for` loop... Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a little bit of recursivity for that too (just adding this for more infos ).

```
public static void run25(ref int x, ref int y)
{
    if(x <= 25)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine($"x = {x}");
        x++;
        run25(ref x, ref y);
    }
    if (y <= 25)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" >> y = {y}");
        y++;
        x = 1;
        run25(ref x, ref y);
    }
    else return ;
}
```

you can  use that as follow :

```
public static void Main (string[] args) 
{
    int _x = 1;
    int _y = 1;
    run25(ref _x, ref _y); // once it's done , _x and _y values are 26 .
}
```

Comment: well I didn't downvote it, but it is an awfully convoluted way of doing things which can be done with two simple nested loops - at least maybe pass in the loop size instead of calling the function run25...

Comment: @seesharper as i said  **(just adding this for more infos )** , I would not use that either , would totally just go for 2 "nested" loops .